# Any Phone Adapter for Router/Modem?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, adapter, phone

I have Comcast as an ISP and want to add phone service. I am currently using a router/modem (Motorola Surfboard SBG6580) which does not have a phone jack.  Is there an adapter I can use so I can plug a phone line into the router/modem or are there phones that use ethernet connections for phone service?

Comment: They will have to come out to your house and run a phone line. There are many services that use your internet to make phone calls on but they also charge a monthly fee so just do your research and find which you prefer.

Comment: There are phones that have Eth connections and there are devices that will translate PSTN to Ethernet - they run a voice protocol (such as SIP) over it to the endpoint server. To make use of this, you need to subscribe to a VoIP service and they'll provide the configuration you need for your device to connect. To @John1024's example, MagicJack is a service provider with a built-in configuration in their adapter. You simply plug in a PSTN phone and it will connect to MagicJack's services. There are other examples that are not proprietary as well as VoIP phones, such as Cisco or Avaya.

Comment: The short answer is if you want Comcast phone service you will need a different modem.  They will lease you one or you can buy one.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask Comcast to provide a phone line, they can come to your house, provide all the hardware, and do the installation for you.

Alternatively, yes, you can buy an adapter that connects your phone to ethernet.  One such adapter is [MagicJack](http://www.magicjack.com/index.html):

[image]

You can see two ports in the image above.  One is for ethernet.  The other is a standard phone jack.  (A third connector, not visible, goes to the wall wart power supply.)

In my experience, magicjack is *much* less expensive than comcast but an ISP, like comcast or AT&T, will provide *much* better personal service.  You will likely want to investigate [competitors](https://www.google.com/search?q=magicjack+competitors).

**To be clear, I am not advocating for any vendor here.  I am just pointing out that what you ask for does exist.**